# How could I model this with a polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An engineer is designing a storage compartment in a spacecraft. The compartment must be 2 meters longer than it is wide and its depth must be 1 meter less than its width. The volume of the compartment must be 8 cubic meters. 
What polynomial would model the volume of the compartment. 
Roots=dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let the dimensions be $L \times W \times H$  The volume is $LWH$.  The problem gives you two relations between the variables, so plug those in.